Problem with running trainer.train() function while fine tuning BERT
When i run trainer.train() it says the following
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-4dc51e76955e> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 trainer.train()
      2 model.save_pretrained("ner_model")
      3 tokenizer.save_pretrianed("tokenizer")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py in get_train_tfdataset(self)
    147 
    148         self.total_train_batch_size = self.args.train_batch_size * self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps
--> 149         self.num_train_examples = self.train_dataset.cardinality().numpy()
    150 
    151         if self.num_train_examples < 0:

AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'cardinality'

I have seen this example on hugging face documentation and it is correct
